# Is there anyway to enter text into a ::before element?

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, dynamics-crm

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to perform automated tests on a customised dynamics 365 website. On the page, there is a web element, contained within 2 iframe elements, denoted by `::before`.

I want to access this element and enter some text into it.

My access code looks like this:

```
get {
    _Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[title='Designer']")));
    _Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(_Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[title^='Description']")));
    return _Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("::before"));
}
```

I have the following methods to enter text into the element once it is returned by the get method. My issue at the moment is that I can't select the element.

```
public static void ClearField(IWebElement inputField) {
    inputField.Click();
    inputField.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
    inputField.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);
    }

public static void SetTextField(IWebElement textField, string value) {
    ClearField(textField);
    textField.Click();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    textField.SendKeys(value);
}
```

The error message I get is as follows:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"::before"}
```

EDIT:
The html for the element I want to select is as follows (due to the size of the html I have only included the last part in the final iframe)

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    title="Description rich text editor" aria-describedby="cke_70" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"
    aria-label="Description rich text editor">
    #document
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" style="overflow-y: hidden;">

    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body tabindex="0" aria-label="Press ALT 0 for help" contenteditable="true"
        class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr" spellcheck="true"
        style="font-size: 9pt; font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, sans-serif; height: auto; min-height: auto;"
        data-msdyn-rteplaceholder="Enter text...">
        ::before
        <br>
    </body>

    </html>
</iframe>
```

The element on the web page looks like this:
[image]

Comment: before what?  That's usually used to select the node before the current one, but it doesn't look like you specify what it's before.  It sounds like you need to get the input element and then send keys to it.  (you probably don't need to use "::before" at all... use path-based locators only as a last resort)